# Postfix forwarding to googlemail

Tags: gmail, postfix-mta, email-forwarding

I have a Problem with my virtual Server and the Combination of forwarding mails to googlemail.

I thry to forward mails to my googlemail-account, in the mail.log seems everything ok, but the mails never arrived.

Line in the mail.log:

```
postfix/smtp[3496]: F354E10E145: to=<xxxxx@gmail.com>, orig_to=<xxxxx@plockbrothers.de>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.26]:25, delay=0.96, delays=0.3/0/0.07/0.59, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1420233196 ev12si92450098wjc.67 - gsmtp)
```

When I´m forwarding the mails for example to an web.de account, everything works fine. The mails arrived.

Anybody an Idea?

Comment: Did you check for the mails in your spam folder?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing happen, thing is: they do arrive - but they do not appear in the Inbox or anywhere. However they still can be found in "All Mail"!

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution. The Mails arrived, but they dosn't appear in the inbox.
When you forwarded mails to the same address from where you sended it, the mail will not been shown by googlemail cause its the same mail like the mail in the outbox.